# Django - Get sum of two dates for unique fields

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I have a model that has type(CharField), start_time(DateTimeField) and end_time(DateTimeField).

I would like to calculate the sum of the total time (end_time - start_time) for each type in seconds using an ORM query.

```
ie) type1, 2016-01-01T10:00:00Z, 2016-01-01T10:00:10Z

type2, 2016-01-01T10:00:00Z, 2016-01-01T10:00:10Z

type1, 2016-01-01T10:00:00Z, 2016-01-01T10:00:10Z

OUTPUT: type1 = 20, type2=10
```

This is what I have so far for the query: 
latest_downtime_list.values('type').order_by('type').annotate(total=Sum('???'))

The problem I am having is being able to take the difference of the two datetimes and converting it to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `F` expression here:

```
latest_downtime_list.values('type')
                    .order_by('type')
                    .annotate(total=Sum(F('end_time') - F('start_time')))
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when trying to traverse through the query list: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'

start_time is set with the model default datetime.now and setting end_time as a string in the 8601 format (2016-01-01T10:00:10Z).